# error while returning begin pointer of an iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the QSLIM tools on Ubuntu 18.04 (C++) for mesh simplification (http://mgarland.org/software/qslim.html), and for this, I am following the steps in https://github.com/alecjacobson/qslim/issues/2 . When I arrive to the step :

```
cd ../mixkit/
make -C src
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 MxDynBlock.h:66:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin()’
 typename MxBlock<T>::const_iterator end() const { return begin()+size(); }
```

Here is the class definition:

```
include "MxBlock.h"
template<class T>
class MxDynBlock : public MxBlock<T>
{
    private:
        int fill;

    public:

        ...

        typename MxBlock<T>::iterator end()       { return begin()+size(); } //<=====
        typename MxBlock<T>::const_iterator end() const { return begin()+size(); }//<====

        void push_back(const T& t) { add(t); }
};
```

the two funcions begin() and end() are defined in the included file "MxBlock.h" in the class MxBlock as following :

```
template<classT>
class MxBlock {
private:
T*block;
protected:
//...
public:
iterator begin(){return block;}
const_iteraor begin() const {return block;}
iterator end(){return begin() + size;}
const_iterator end() const{return begin() + size;}
...//end of class MxBlock
```

Any idea to fix this ?
Thank you

Comment: And where exactly did you define `begin()`?

Comment: sorry, indeed i had to specify. I edited and specified

Comment: Maybe, just maybe putting `MxBlock<T>::` before `begin()`s in `MxDynBlock` helps.

Comment: I just tried my `MxBlock<T>::begin()` theory and it worked in [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler). But I changed `typename MxBlock<T>::iterator` with `int`. Because I could not find the `iterator` inner class in [source](http://lvelho.impa.br/a48/heap_8h-source.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as proposed by Kao in the comments, I added MxBlock:: before begin()